# Can I put three NM 12 awg wires into a breaker box knockout?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I am running out of knockout on my breaker box and most of my knockouts have 2 NM wires going into them. Can I put 3 NM wires in one knockout? Are there restrictions to how many NM wires or size that can go into a main panel knockout?

Comment: Are these 12/2 or 12/3 cables?

Comment: What size are the knockouts?

Comment: if you don't have enough holes you are allowed to make new ones. Be careful not to damage any wires while making new holes.

Comment: They are 12/2 wires. The clamp opening measure 3/4 inch.

Answer (score 12):

### You can, but you need a 3/4" KO and the correct clamp to do so

If you're working with a 3/4" or larger knockout, you *can* get 3 12/2 or 12/3 NM cables into it.  You just need a cable clamp that's listed/rated for that many cables; fortunately, the Arlington NM842 is cheap and fits the bill perfectly here.  It can even accept 4 12/2, or 2 12/3 and 1 12/2, or a 12/3 and two 12/2s.

Answer (score 6):

Clamps/fittings need to be NRTL (UL/ETL) Listed, and the instructions on or with the fittings are part of the Listing, and will indicate the number and type of cables allowed.

Comment: I bought the clamps from home depot. They say Halex D on one side and Halex 5101 on the other side.